# two files Permutations and combinations

Tags: shell, file-io, permutation

There are two files a.txt b.txt inside their own ten words
I want the contents of permutations than the output to the screen
Like this

```
a [1] b [1]
a [1] b [2]
.
.
.
a [10] b [10]
Total 100
```

I want this array into a loop to run I do not know how to write
Can a master can guide us to thank

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through file a and b,

```
while read a_line
do
        while read b_line
        do
                echo $a_line $b_line
        done < b
done < a
```

If output sequence is not important, you can use `paste` also

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    (awk "NR>=$i" b; awk "NR<$i" b) | paste a -
done
```

> when FILE is -, read standard input.

`awk "NR>=$i" b; awk "NR<$i" b`, print lines from $i, then print lines from 1 to $i-1

Comment: If there are 100 accounts, passwords, how do I bring to the ftp server automatically in